# Material UI dropdowns using cypress not always working

Tags: material-ui, cypress, dropdown

I've tried many ways, but it doesn't always work. I mean.. it does find the element and click on it...
But doesn't always add value to the dropdown input field. I cannot continue the test since the dropdowns are mandatory fields I need.
**The dropdown input field can't be empty.**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("selectTooltipDropdownOption", (optionText, inputSelector) => {
    cy.getCyInput(inputSelector,{timeout:10000}).click();

    cy.getCyRole("menu").children('li').contains(optionText).trigger("click", { timeout: 10000 });
  
    cy.getCyInput(inputSelector)
      .invoke("prop", "defaultValue")
      .should("contain", optionText);
  });
```

What can I do so the `cy.getCyInput("dropdowninputField")` will always have the value and not be empty?

[image: cypress run]

The dropdown doesn't seem to be a select type; it's a classical select component with additional styles from Material UI. Here's how it looks in HTML. I made the  smaller to be easer to see, and the position is dynamic based on the ID of the elements or component.

```html
<div
  role="tooltip"
  class="jss390"
  style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate3d(317px, 412px, 0px);
    will-change: transform;
  "
  x-placement="bottom"
>
  <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPaper-rounded">
    <ul
      class="MuiList-root jss389 MuiList-padding"
      role="menu"
      tabindex="-1"
      data-cy-action="select-action-root/insured/seller/0/data/address/country"
      style="min-width: 271px"
    >
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="0"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Austria<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Belgium<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        British Virgin Islands<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Bulgaria<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Cayman Islands<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Croatia<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Cyprus<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Czech Republic<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Denmark<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
      <li
        class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="menuitem"
        aria-disabled="false"
      >
        Estonia<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you post HTML of the options `data-cy-action` and not the focus of the test `data-cy-input`?

Comment: @Zoe it was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

Since the test passes ***sometimes***, the "action" parts are correct but flaky result would indicate ***a timing issue***, i.e something asynchronous is not being waited on correctly.

The only waiting you are doing is the last line with `.invoke("prop", "defaultValue").should("contain", optionText)`, so that would be the wrong assertion.

Generally `defaultValue` tells the dropdown what default value to use if the user never picks a value, so it's not changed when a different value is selected.

---

#### Check the internal value or the displayed text

You could check the `value` of the `<input>` element used internally.

```js
cy.getCyInput(inputSelector)
  .find('input')               // this is where the selected value is stored
  .invoke('val')
  .should('eq', <internal-value>)
```

You need to know is what is `<internal-value>`? It could be `optionText` or it could be a code.
For example the `optionText` of "United Kingdom" might have a code of "UK".

Or use the `text` displayed in the label - it's the first child of the top element and has role of "combobox".

```js
cy.getCyInput(inputSelector)
  .find('[role="combobox"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', optionText)
```

Inspect the HTML for the top element (which has attribute `data-cy-input="..."`) to see if this is correct. Since you only show HTML for the menu options, I am making a guess.

If your HTML follows the examples online, it will be something this

- a top level `<div>` with the `data-cy-input` attribute you are passing as `inputSelector`
- a "label" child div that has text of selected option (only ***after*** selection)
- a hidden child input that has value corresponding to the selected option (only ***after*** selection)

```html
<div data-cy-input="data test attribute here">
  <div role="combobox" ...>Selected option text here</div>
  <input aria-hidden="true" ... value="selected option value here">
```